# Audio processing in Android giving lag

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediacodec

I am trying to implement an algorithm that will change the music playing on the fly. I am using OpenMXPlayer for implementing my music player. I have access to the byte and can edit it also, but it gives me a lag when I am playing it on the device. I understand that the lag is because of the time my algorithm takes to modify the byte[]. I need a way to remove the lag. Below is the snippet of the code I am implementing. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
        int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);

        if (res >= 0) {
            if (info.size > 0)  noOutputCounter = 0;

            int outputBufIndex = res;
            ByteBuffer buf = codecOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];

            final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size];
            buf.get(chunk);


            //EDIT THE CHUNK AND WRITE IT IN THE AUDIOTRACK.



            buf.clear();
            if(chunk.length > 0){           
                audioTrack.write(chunk,0,chunk.length);                 
            }
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false);
            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "saw output EOS.");
                sawOutputEOS = true;
            }
```

Comment: Try to implement your algorithm in background thread using asynctask or RX.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work